# devexpress ASPxGridView conditionally show button on row

Tags: button, devexpress, show-hide, aspxgridview

In a DevExpress **ASPxGridView** I need to show / hide a button in every row of the grid, based on some property of the underlying record.
For DevExpress ASPxGridView I can't find something similar to the **GridView.RowDataBound** Event which exists in asp.net Gridview, which can help me to solve the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

after searching more i found that equivalent event for gridview.rowdatabound is  in ASPxGridView is **HtmlRowCreated**

but asper you requirement you may try **HtmlDataCellPrepared** which is usefull to scan each cell of aspxgridview and also we may access data value from other column also here i attach sample code which describe this things.

**ASPX Page**

```
          <dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" OnHtmlDataCellPrepared="ASPxGridView1_HtmlDataCellPrepared" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <Columns>
                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ID">
                        <DataItemTemplate>
                            <dx:ASPxButton ID="btn" runat="server" Text="click me">
                            </dx:ASPxButton>
                        </DataItemTemplate>
                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ItemName">
                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ItemValue">
                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>

                </Columns>
            </dx:ASPxGridView>
```

**CS page :**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ASPxGridView1.DataSource = GetData();
        ASPxGridView1.DataBind();
    }

    public DataTable GetData()
    {
        DataTable Table = new DataTable();
        Table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        Table.Columns.Add("ItemName", typeof(string));
        Table.Columns.Add("ItemValue", typeof(string));
        Table.Rows.Add(1, "A", "AA");
        Table.Rows.Add(2, "B", "BB");
        Table.Rows.Add(2, "B", "BB");
        Table.Rows.Add(2, "A", "BB");
        return Table;
    }

    protected void ASPxGridView1_HtmlDataCellPrepared(object sender, ASPxGridViewTableDataCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.DataColumn.FieldName == "ID")
        {
            ASPxButton textBox = ASPxGridView1.FindRowCellTemplateControl(e.VisibleIndex, e.DataColumn, "btn") as ASPxButton;
            if (Convert.ToString(e.GetValue("ItemName")).Equals("B"))
            {
                textBox.Text = Convert.ToString(e.CellValue);
                textBox.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                textBox.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

in above code i have one button column which is hide based on ItemName column.

i hope this may help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion I will try it later. For the moment, I am working on another idea: use a function for the attribute Visible of the ASPxButton which must be hide on some conditions.